# Как получить данные из shared_prefs.xml на другом устройстве

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

В процессе разработки столкнулся с необходимостью сохранять некоторые объекты для последующей работы. Сериализую их в JSON и сохраняю в shared_prefs в виде строки. НА включении приложения делаю десериализацию и все работает отлично. В процессе разработки поменял себе девайс. И, так как пока не реализовано сохранение никуда, кроме shared_prefs, решил просто взять и перенсти файл на новое устройство. Установил приложение, заменил соответствующие shared_prefs в папке и не увидел никакого результата. То есть ошибки нет, но и десериализации не происходит. Попытка отлогировать то что я получаю из shared_prefs показала, что я получаю "", то есть пустую строку.

Можно ли каким нибудь образом перенести данные таким образом и почему так происходит? По идее название prefs в каталоге и ключи для чтения одни и те же, значит какой то другой параметр определяет принадлежность к девайсу?

UPDATE:

Проделал ещё несколько па с prefs. Если раньше было так, что вне зависимости от того что я делаю, содержимое папки живет и читается нормально, то сейчас, со скопированными происходит следующее. Если я устанавливаю приложение - prefs пустой, что логично, я закидываю свои файлы и устанавливаю приложение поверх (раньше prefs сохранялись), получаю обнуление prefs - всё из них пропалает, остается голый файл. Если запускать без переустановки, то (магия) из prefs читается только "[]", без содержимого (выше я писал, что сохраняю `JSONArray`: "[.......]", то есть ....... не читается, читаются только квадратные скобки). То же показала и попытка пройтись итератором по `prefs.getAll()`. Значение по ключу он получает, но в виде "[]", и только. При этом prefs НЕ обнуляются. Кто нибудь встречался с такой магией?

Comment: Получать пустую строку вы можете как значение по умолчанию при ненахождении значения по ключу. Может у вас файл не так назван.

Comment: исключено, и название файла и ключ доступа к строке указаны соответственно в классе и в ресурсах